# General understanding of OOP Languages

Tags: oop

Why a language has to be object oriented in order to define local variables?

For example Cobol allowed the definition of local variable only since 2002 because only then the language became object oriented

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by local variable. For example, any variable defined within a function (in Python, R...) is local to the function's environment. For a variable to be local, it needs to be local to some given environment and an object defines its own environment and, as such, is one way of creating local variables. Did I totally misunderstand the question?

Comment: Yes I mean by local variable defined in a function that is possible only when the language is OOP am I wrong?not clear...

Comment: @hannah Examples of the non-oop (functional?) modern languages that has no concept of local variables?

Comment: @hannah I do believe you are wrong and that OOP and scoping do not have much in common. Then again, I am not a computer scientist so I might be the one who is wrong. Stata seems to have local variables without being OOP.

Comment: Not sure if 15 years old language dialect can be called _modern_... Still I agree with @Chobi, concept of local variables isn't dependent on OOP-ness, just limitations of implementation of old Cobol dialect...

Answer (score 2):

Variable scope is completely different from the development paradigm or procedural versus object oriented.

Most languages include some form of variable scope, way before OOP was invented.

Answer (score 2):

Programming languages like Pascal (inventend in 1969) and C (also around 1969) are purely procedural programming languages and had local variables from the beginning. There might be other programming languages preceding these two and already allowing local variables, but I'm to lazy to do further research.

So, no, a programming language does not have to be object oriented to have local variables.